# Set Profile with ChromeDriver And Stay Logged

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need help for stay logged in VBA Selenium Chrome. Every new link it opens i have to loggin again. I can't force it to read my cookies and stay logged.

I've already tried:

```
driver.SetProfile "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default", True

driver.AddArgument ("C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default")

driver.AddArgument ("--no-sandbox")
```

The path is ok, it opens with the correct path that i passed, but it's continue don't kept me logged. Every link it opens i have to loggin again. I've read a lot of foruns, i can't solve this.

Could someone help me, please?

**EDIT:**

Problem solved, i'll not delete if someone has the same problem maybe it can help, when you look the path is:

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

But you must write only until "User Data", "Default" is automatically added in the end, otherwise the path will be 2 folders "Default" at the end.

I only changed it and wrote:

driver.SetProfile "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data", True

Now it's perfect.